# Flexslider, no quickscroll to begin

Tags: flexslider

I use the "FLexslider - Jquery" plugin.

I don't like it when animationLoop is true and it reaches the end of the slides, it does a quick scroll to the start. I would like it to instead keep a continuous loop. I did NOT see an option for this.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the date of your post, can we assume that you're using Flexslider2? If you are, the option animationLoop should already be set as TRUE and should clone your first and last slides so it will always loop instead of "reset" back to the beginning. Can you paste your code on what you have and lets get going from there.

Ex:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  slideshow: false,
  animationLoop: false,
  video: true,
  controlsContainer: '.flex-nav',
  manualControls: ".flex-nav_tab li",
  start: function() {
    console.log('changing slide')
  }
});
```